# Getting Long-term load statistics from RHEL Cluster?

Tags: linux, unix, cluster

Is there any straightforward record/poll of long term load record instead of the usual 1,5,15 minute load values?

Background: Trying to convince faculty that current cluster solution is underutilized XX% of the time and could be used for BOINC / etc during periods of 'silence'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/index.php) and [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/).  You can use them to poll, record, and display aggregated results as graphs the performance of just about anything on a server.  There are plenty of [templates](http://docs.cacti.net/templates) available to get you started recording server data.

From RRDtool's webpage:

> RRDtool is the OpenSource industry
>   standard, high performance data
>   logging and graphing system for time
>   series data.

From Cacti's webpage:

> Cacti is a complete network graphing
>   solution designed to harness the power
>   of RRDTool's data storage and graphing
>   functionality. Cacti provides a fast
>   poller, advanced graph templating,
>   multiple data acquisition methods, and
>   user management features out of the
>   box. All of this is wrapped in an
>   intuitive, easy to use interface that
>   makes sense for LAN-sized
>   installations up to complex networks
>   with hundreds of devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Munin on it.